# cannot connect to memcached server with sasl enabled

Tags: ubuntu, memcached, sasl

I'm having some difficulty setting up SASL on a memcached instance on AWS running ubuntu.

Specs:

- memcached-1.4.24: compiled with --enable-sasl, started with -S
- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- connecting from Ubuntu 12.04.5

When attempting to connect, I see the following in the memcached logs:

```
<31 new binary client connection.
<31 Read binary protocol data:
<31    0x80 0x20 0x00 0x00
<31    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<31    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<31    0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00
<31    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<31    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
authenticated() in cmd 0x20 is true
>31 Writing bin response:
>31   0x81 0x20 0x00 0x00
>31   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
>31   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x2e
>31   0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00
>31   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
>31   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<31 Read binary protocol data:
<31    0x80 0x21 0x00 0x0a
<31    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<31    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0a
<31    0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00
<31    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<31    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
authenticated() in cmd 0x21 is true
mech:  ``DIGEST-MD5'' with 0 bytes of data
SASL (severity 5): DIGEST-MD5 server step 1
sasl result code:  1
>31 Writing bin response:
>31   0x81 0x21 0x00 0x00
>31   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x21
>31   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x78
>31   0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00
>31   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
>31   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<31 connection closed.
SASL (severity 5): DIGEST-MD5 common mech dispose
```

I'm testing connections from the client using the sample client, sasl_test from the blog post: http://blog.memcachier.com/2014/11/05/ubuntu-libmemcached-and-sasl-support/

It shows the following output:

```
$ ./sasl_test user password ec2-52-6-196-187.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Set failed: WRITE FAILURE
```

I have confirmed that the test client can connect to other servers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing exact same errr while trying to connect with DIGEST-MD5 using spy-memcached library.

In my case, it turns out spy-memcached library doesn't support Auth with 'DIGEST-MD5' mechanism.

Check if sasl_test is supporting DIGEST-MD5.